# How do I make the ScopeBar appear when someone clicks in the search field of UISearchBar on iphone

Tags: iphone

I would like to make the ScopeBar appear when a user clicks on the search field of the UISearchBar just like the email search bar works.  I can have the scope bar always on or always off but can't seem to control its display when a user clicks on the search bar.   I have used [searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES] and it does change the property correctly but how do I then display it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix.  You can do it all in Interface Builder.  I used a  'Search Bar and Search Display Controller' instead of a 'Search Bar' and unchecked the 'Shows Scope Bar' in Interface Builder.  When a user clicks on the Search Field now the Scope Bar Displays.